# what happen when ">" is applied to character in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset as the following:

```
  state                substance sample.result
1  <NA> MAXIMUM NORMALIZED DP/DT           8.5
2  <NA>         Moisture Content            11
3    OH  Lead, Inorganic (as Pb)     0.0485974
4    OH  Lead, Inorganic (as Pb)     0.0292245
5    OH  Lead, Inorganic (as Pb)     0.0620832
6    OH  Lead, Inorganic (as Pb)             0
```

but the sample.result is of character type and I am wondering what will happen if I use the following code to subset:

```
health = subset(data, sample.result >0)
```

Will this automatically convert the character value into appropriate numeric value?

Comment: Check out `?as.numeric`

Comment: At any rate, in regard to this question - The moral of the story is ... don't risk it.  Use `health = subset(data, as.numeric(sample.result) > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coercion is the opposite to your hopes. Coercion to "character" occurs and the lexical ordering is OS dependent, so the result of the suggested comparison will depend on whether "-" is before or after "0" on your machine.

See: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Comparison.html

Comment: *... will depend on whether "-" is before or after "0" on your machine* - What does that mean?

Comment: Different OSes (and locales) have different collation ordering. Typically alpha ordering with no diacritcals will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the class of the column. If the `sample.result`column is a factor, it will not work.

The above comments seem to show that there is some ambiguity in whether or not R evaluates "-1.5" as greater or less than zero, so you should perhaps avoid using `>` on the column if it is of class `character`.

If the column is of class `numeric` it will be fine.

You can check the class of the column using `class(data$sample.result)`

It would probably be best, however, to explicitly convert sample.result to numeric using:

```
health  = subset(data, as.numeric(as.character(sample.result)))
```

The extra `as.character` ensures that if it was previousl.y a factor, that it is handled correctly (try converting a factor to a numeric with just `as.numeric` to see why).